# Math problem from logical game

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

We have a set of arrows and can start from any point. Every next point must be chosen in direction of previous and can be used only one time. We need to visit all points. Direction of last point doesn't matter.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\rightarrow&\leftarrow&\downarrow&\leftarrow\\
\downarrow&\downarrow&\leftarrow&\downarrow\\
\rightarrow&\leftarrow&\uparrow&\uparrow\\
\rightarrow&\uparrow&\leftarrow&\uparrow\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
If make numeration
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
5&6&7&8\\
9&10&11&12\\
13&14&15&16\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
the creator of game gives the solution: 1,3,15,14,6,10,9,11,7,5,13,16,8,12,4,2.

So if $a$ length of the row and $b$ length of column, we can make two similar function.

First function $S(a,b)$ count:

1. Quantity of different sets, which have at least one start point that have solution - $S_{0}(a,b)$.
2. Summary quantity of different start points in those sets - $S(a,b)$.
3. Summary quantity of different (for each start point) directions from start to last point (start and last point can be same, but have two or more different directions) - $S_{v}(a,b)$.

So for $b=1$ and

1. $a=1$ we have:
   $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(1), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(1), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \uparrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(1), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \downarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(1).
2. $a=2$ we have:
   $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\rightarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(12), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\uparrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(12), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\downarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(12), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(12,21), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\leftarrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(21), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\uparrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(21), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\downarrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(21).
3. $a=3$ we have $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\rightarrow\rightarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(123), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\rightarrow\uparrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(123), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\rightarrow\downarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(123), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\rightarrow\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(123,132,312,231), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\uparrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(132,231), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\downarrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(132,231), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\rightarrow}\leftarrow\color{red}{\rightarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(213), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\rightarrow}\leftarrow\color{red}{\uparrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(213), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\rightarrow}\leftarrow\color{red}{\downarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(213), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\leftarrow\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(132,213,231,321), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\leftarrow}\rightarrow\color{red}{\leftarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(312), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\uparrow}\rightarrow\color{red}{\leftarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(312), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\downarrow}\rightarrow\color{red}{\leftarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(312), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\leftarrow}\color{red}{\leftarrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(321), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\uparrow}\color{red}{\leftarrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(321), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\downarrow}\color{red}{\leftarrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(321).

Second function $F(a,b)$ count:

1. Quantity of different sets, which have at least one start point that have solution for chosen last point (which have undefined direction) - $F_{0}(a,b)$.
2. Summary quantity of different start points in those sets - $F(a,b)$.
3. Summary quantity of different (for each start point) directions from start to last point (start and last point can be same, but have two or more different directions) - $F_{v}(a,b)$.

So for $b=1$ and

1. $a=1$ we have $\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(1).
2. $a=2$ we have $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow0\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(12), $\begin{bmatrix}
   0\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(21).
3. $a=3$ we have $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow\color{red}{\rightarrow}0\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(123), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \color{red}{\rightarrow}\leftarrow0\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(213), $\begin{bmatrix}
   0\rightarrow\color{red}{\leftarrow}\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(312), $\begin{bmatrix}
   \rightarrow0\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(132,231), $\begin{bmatrix}
   0\color{red}{\leftarrow}\leftarrow\\
   \end{bmatrix}$(321).

This function use sets with length $a-1$ from special function $T(a,b)$ with adding undefined last point. Then we put to this undefined point $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ (in our case, because $b=1$), but if we put $\rightarrow$ and $\leftarrow$ it special case, which we count with $T(a,b)$. Another words, $S(a,b)=T(a,b)+2F(a,b)$.

We can be sure, that for $n>1$

$$S_{0}(1,n)=S_{0}(n,1)=(n+5)2^{n-2}$$
$$S(1,n)=S(n,1)=(n-2)(n+4)2^{n-2}+8$$
$$S_{v}(1,n)=S_{v}(n,1)=4\cdot n!$$

and

$$F_{0}(1,n)=F_{0}(n,1)=(n+2)2^{n-3}$$
$$F(1,n)=F(n,1)=(n-2)(n+1)2^{n-3}+2$$
$$F_{v}(1,n)=F_{v}(n,1)=n!$$

Also

$$S_{0}(1,1)=S(1,1)=S_{v}(1,1)=4$$
$$F_{0}(1,1)=F(1,1)=F_{v}(1,1)=1$$

How can I find it for any $a,b$?

Comment: Is your question about the game or are you only interested in these auxiliary functions? Also, the definition of $S$ and $F$ is not very clear to me (what sets? what does summary quantity mean?).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, game illustrates where from problem rising. What concretely are you don't understand? I can add trivial cases for small $n$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, the definitions of the $S$'s can be understood from the $a=3$ example:  $S_0(3,1)=16$ counts the number of arrangements of the arrows that admit solutions (out of $4^3=64$ possible arrangements of three arrows in a row), $S(3,1)=22$ counts the number of *black* arrows, which indicate a possible starting point for a solution, and $S_v(3,1)=24$ counts the number of listed triples of numbers, each of which describes a solution for the triples of arrows they follow. I'm with you, though, regarding the definition of the $F$'s. It'd be nice to see an example for them.

Comment: Minor aside: This isn't really a combinatorial *game*, at least not in the technical sense of having multiple players strategizing their moves so as to win.

Comment: @BarryCipra, thank you for helping! Examples was added. I really have no ideas about tags. Can you compute some first cases for $b=2$? I bad at prog, but good in intuition.

Comment: @user514787, the additional examples do help.  Have you computed things for small $(a,2)$'s, e.g. $(2,2)$ and $(3,2)$?

Comment: Analyzing the puzzle given, there are two solution circuits: 1-3-11-7-5-13-15-14-6-10-9-12-8-16-4-2(-1) and 1-3-15-14-6-10-9-11-7-5-13-16-8-12-4-2(-1). For a random start point these give 32 solutions, of course; I don't think there are any other solutions.

Comment: @BarryCipra, $S_{0}(2,2)=26, S(2,2)=S_{v}(2,2)=32$, $F_{0}(2,2)=F(2,2)=F_{v}(2,2)=8$, $F_{0}(3,2)=56, F(3,2)=F_{v}(3,2)=60$. I count them with drawing all those sets with arrows by hand, like an old-time mathematician. It takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Joffan, very interesting! I wish to group sets for easy computing all those solutions.

Comment: @Joffan, what is also interesting in your example - it shows, that set can have more, than one circuit solution. But is there a limit of them, no matter how large the set? For example, there is no more, than 7 diagonal of regular polygon which intersects in one point (except center).

Comment: @BarryCipra, you asked about those 2 cases to verify results, which you will compute?

Comment: I would definitely be leery of a hand count for this problem; it can be notoriously easy to miss solutions. I'd also be very surprised if there were  any clean  explicit formulas for the quantities you're asking about, because a formula (generally) implies a measure of structure and I suspect that even identifying a valid solution is NP-complete.

Comment: What is a "solution"? Why isn't 1,4,2 a solution? Is there some requirement you forgot to tell us?

Comment: @bof, thank you for comment! Main requirement was added. Don't it obvious for you? Previous commentators has no problem with it.

Comment: What is the name of this game? Does it have solution for any combination of arrows?

Comment: @IvanBunin, thank you for comment! It actually not a game, but just a level #49 of app named "red" created by Bart Bonte. Also there are finite number of combinations of arrows, which have at least one solution (exactly $S_{0}(a,b)$ and $F_{0}(a,b)$).