# Functions of perimeter and area of parts from two circles

Tags: functions, circles, area

We have a circle with radius $1$. Next we draw a circle with radius $r$, whose center lay on the first circle, so $0\leqslant r\leqslant2$. When $r=0$ there is only $1$ part with
$$C(0)=2\pi, S(0)=\pi$$
When $r=2$ there are $2$ parts with
$$C_{1}(2)=2\pi, S_{1}(2)=\pi$$
$$C_{2}(2)=6\pi, S_{2}(2)=3\pi$$
For all other cases there are $3$ parts. There is only $1$ case when $2$ of them are the same ($r=1$)
$$C_{1}(1)=\frac{4\pi}{3}, S_{1}(1)=\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$C_{2}(1)=C_{3}(1)=2\pi, S_{2}(1)=S_{3}(1)=\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Are there functions for perimeter and area for each of $3$ parts when $0<r<2$?

Comment: For the area of the overlapping region see equation 14 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html). For the perimeter of the region use equation 9 to find the cord length and equation 13 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html) to find the angle from each circle center to the cord.

Comment: @Jens, thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome. And thank you for the alternative upvotes :-)

Comment: @Jens, if you like puzzles, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777276.